# How to add multiple wrapper lists into single list

Tags: list, salesforce, wrapper, apex

I have created apex class to pull multiple object records into single list. Where objects does not have any relationship (lets say account, contact, lead. Consider account and contact dont have any relationship). I used for loop seperately for each object and saved into wrapperlist. For three objects I have three wrapper list. Now big challenge is I need to add three wrappers(wrapAccount, wrapContact, wrapLead)  into single list. So in that list I need all three objects records.

```
@Auraenabled(cacheable=true)  
public static List<sObject> wrapData() {
    List<WrapperContact> wrapContact = new List<WrapperContact>();
    List<WrapperAccount> wrapAccount = new List<WrapperAccount>();
    List<WrapperLead> wrapLead = new List<WrapperLead>();
    
    for(Contact ct : [select id, name from Contact LIMIT 10]){          
        wrapContact.add(new WrapperContact(ct));            
    }
    for(Account acct : [select id, name from Account LIMIT 10]){          
        wrapAccount.add(new WrapperAccount(acct));            
    }
    for(Lead ld : [select id, name from Lead LIMIT 10]){          
        wrapLead.add(new WrapperLead(ld));            
    }
    system.debug('wrapContact'+wrapContact);
    system.debug('wrapAccount'+wrapAccount);
    system.debug('wrapLead'+wrapLead);

 List<SObject> s = new List<SObject>{
        new Contact(),
        new Account(),
        new Lead()            
    };

 public class WrapperAccount{
            
    @Auraenabled
    public Account ac{get;set;}
     
    public WrapperAccount(Account acct){
        ac=acct;
    }
    
}

 public class WrapperContact{
    @Auraenabled
    public Contact cont{get;set;}
          
    public WrapperContact(Contact ct){
        cont=ct;
    }
                  
}

 public class WrapperLead{
           
    @Auraenabled
    public Lead ldd{get;set;}
        
    public WrapperLead(Lead ld){
        ldd=ld;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about stripping it down to one wrapper class with an extra property for the object type and instead of a concrete class make it return an sObject, then use a switch statement when rendering/working with them to cast it back to the correct type?

Answer (score 0):

An example of what I mean:

```
public class tester {
    @Auraenabled(cacheable=true)  
    public static List<Wrapper> wrapData() {
        
        List<Wrapper> wrap = new List<Wrapper>();

        for(Contact ct : [select id, name from Contact LIMIT 10]){          
            wrap.add(new Wrapper(ct,'contact'));            
        }
        for(Account acct : [select id, name from Account LIMIT 10]){          
            wrap.add(new Wrapper(acct,'account'));            
        }
        for(Lead ld : [select id, name from Lead LIMIT 10]){          
            wrap.add(new Wrapper(ld, 'lead'));            
        }

        return wrap;
    }

    public class Wrapper{
                
        @Auraenabled
        public sObject ac{get;set;}
        public string objType{get;set;}
        
        public Wrapper(sObject obj, string objtype){
            ac=obj;
            objType= objtype;
        }
        
    }

     
}
```

You can then loop through the returned wrapData and display them as you like using a switch and converting them to the correct type. There may be better methods though.